# After migration to Androidx SwitchCompat is white

Tags: android, androidx, switchcompat

I've migrated my project to `AndroidX`. My `MainActivity` extend `FragmentActivity`  my first `SwitchCompat` looks all white, it doesn't have any color at all when I first time come to that screen. [SwitchCompat is white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SU1s.png).  All other SwitchCompact under it are with correct color. If I press back and come again to that screen, my first `SwitchCompact` receive correct color and looks fine.

If I change that my `MainActivty` extend `AppCompactActivity`, then everything is ok when I first time reach that screen. Does anyone know where is problem here because before migration my `MainActivity` also extend `FragmentActivity` and everything was fine.
My `xml` code is the same in the both case:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide code of your layout?

Comment: Hi Dimitrii. Problem is not in code. Code is the same. But when my MianActivity extend AppCompcatActivity behavior is fine, but if I extend FragmentActivity then behavior is like I descriped. Code in layout is same all the time.

Comment: Same happened for me. The issue comes from Theme.AppCompat.DayNight theme

Answer (score 1):

I didn`t go deep why this problem occurs when you extend FragmentActivity.  but to show appropriate colors on the action event of  "SwitchCompat" can achievable by using custom track and thumb.

**your switch button**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/sw_autoplay"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="4dp"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            android:theme="@style/SwitchButtonTheme"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
            app:track="@drawable/track" />
```

**thumb**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
        <stroke android:width=".5dp" android:color="#A4A0A0" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp" />
        <stroke android:width=".5dp" android:color="#57F47F" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**track**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <stroke android:width=".3dp" android:color="#A4A0A0" />
        <size android:height="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        <solid android:color="#57F47F" />
        <stroke android:width=".3dp" android:color="#A4A0A0" />
        <size android:height="20dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

It`s just for when you want you to use "FragmentActivity".